# Complex structure on product of two $n$-dimensional real manifolds

Tags: complex-geometry

Let $M$, $N$ be $n$-dimensional real manifolds. Does $M\times N$ admits a complex structure? If not, are there known condidtions ensuring that $M\times N$ admits a complex structure?

Comment: It's not a complex manifold... better ask whether it admits a complex structure / a structure of complex manifold.

Comment: In general, the answer is no. In particular, if either $M$ or $N$ are non-orientable, so is their product, which rules out the existence of a complex structure. I'm not sure that there are any known non-trivial conditions which ensure that $M \times N$ admits a complex structure.

Comment: You are probably thinking of the statement that if $V$ is an $n$-dimensional real vector space, then $V\oplus V$ acquires a complex structure via the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. If so, then first consider the fact that if $W$ is another $n$-dimensional real vector space, then one needs to *pick* an isomorphism between $V$ and $W$ to have such a complex structure. Mimicking this, one could ask whether $M\times M$ has a complex structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to take $M$ and $N$ to be connected. Note that they cannot have boundary. Furthermore, as complex manifolds are orientable, $M$ and $N$ must also be orientable.

If $n = 1$, then $M, N \in \{\mathbb{R}, S^1\}$. Note that $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ has a complex structure, in fact, precisely two: $\mathbb{D}$ and $\mathbb{C}$. In addition, $\mathbb{R}\times S^1 = S^1\times \mathbb{R}$ and $S^1\times S^1$ have uncountably many complex structures (annuli and tori respectively).

If $n = 2$, then $M$ and $N$ are orientable surfaces. These always admit complex structures, and therefore, so do their products.

Already for $n = 3$, we do not have a complete answer. In this case, the manifold $M\times N$ always admits an almost complex structure, but it is not clear when it admits an integrable one (i.e. a complex structure). This is a major open problem in complex geometry:

> If a manifold admits an almost complex structure, does it admit a complex structure?

The answer is known to be false in real dimension four, but completely open in higher dimensions.

For $n = 4$, the manifold $M\times N$ may not even admit an almost complex structure. For example, $M = N = S^4$. Theorem 1 of [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938370900315) of Heaps completely characterises which closed eight-manifolds admit an almost complex structure. In principle, this could be used to determine what $M$ and $N$ could be, at least in the compact case.

Comment: Thank you! when n=4, why is there not almost complex structure? We can define $J :T_{x}M\rightarrow T_{y}N$ and $J :T_{y}N\rightarrow T_{y}M$ such that J^{2}=-Id? Then J is an almost complex structure. Is it true?

Comment: That can work at a point, but you cannot get an almost complex structure on $M\times N$ that way. Note that $T(M\times N) \cong \pi_1^*TM\oplus\pi_2^*TN$ and $\pi_1^*TM \not\cong \pi_2^*TN$ so there is no such map $J : \pi_1^*TM \to \pi_2^*TN$.

Comment: I checked the definition of almost complex structure. I think almost complex structures only need to be defined point by point.

Comment: It needs to be smoothly varying, your construction won't be.

Comment: In my first comment, I should have said that $\pi_1^*TM$ and $\pi_2^*TN$ are not isomorphic unless they are trivial.

Comment: Not relevant to the question. But the product of a circle with the real line admits indeed a one parameter family of different complex structures. These are parameterized by the so-called modulus of an annulus.

Comment: @MartindeBorbon: You're absolutely right, I don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are asking if $M \times N$ admits a complex structure.
I believe that there is no result known on this question, although we might have something to say about the existence of an almost complex structure for which both factors are totally real.
Once again we can quote  [Gromov](https://www.ihes.fr/~gromov/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/SpacesandQuestions.pdf):  Page 30. "How much do we gain in global understanding of a compact $(V, J)$ by assuming that the structure $J$ is integrable (i.e. complex)? It seems nothing at all: there is no single result concerning all compact complex manifolds".

Comment: Thank you! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT: I started to write this answer, and then realized it doesn't really answers the question - I leave it here anyway, just in case]

Let $X=M\times N$, and let $E=\pi_M^*TM$ and $F=\pi_N^*TN$. Note that $TX=E\oplus F$. 
As suggested in Ben McKay's answer, you could first look for the existence of an almost complex structure $J\in End(TX)$, $J^2=-Id$, for which both projections $\pi_M$ and $\pi_N$ have totally real fibers.

This may exist or not. It does for instance under the assumption that there exists an isomorphism of vector bundles $\phi:E\to F$. In that case, define
$$
J:=\left(\matrix{0 &\phi^{-1} \\ -\phi & 0}\right)
$$
In this situation the eigenbundle $T^{1,0}X$ corresponding to $+i$ is isomorphic to $E^{\mathbb{C}}$ in the following way: 
$$
E^{\mathbb{C}}\to T^{1,0}X\quad;\quad v\mapsto v+i\phi(v)
$$
You may want to look for conditions on $\phi$ for $J$ to be integrable.

Comment: Thank you!Thank you!

Comment: Since $E$ is trivial on $N$ and $F$ is trivial on $N$, if they are isomorphic, they are both trivial, so $M$ and $N$ have trivial tangent bundle. It then follows that there is an almost complex structure. For example, any 3-manifolds $M$ and $N$ have trivial tangent bundle, so the resulting $M \times N$ has an almost complex structure with two totally real fibrations.